# To get the notification about the BlackBerry questions tagset

Tags: support, tags, notifications

How can I add some new tag set in my Stack Overflow account to get notification, if a new question is asked by a user for that particular tag set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Head over to [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/), head over to [filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters/), click on New Filter and add the required tags and choose the frequency of the notifications

[image]