# Notification for favourite Tags

Tags: feature-request, support, notifications

I believe all SO users have the same notification area, where the see the hot questions across all the stack exchange sites. The three tabs, **hot questions**, **all sites**, **inbox** indicate the respective question that is hot or commented on. I have seen this feature as broadly classified. Basically If I am active in StackOverflow C# tag, it doesn't make a sense for me to see a hot question from tex.stackexchange.com. I am wondering if this can be customized.

Basically I would like to be updated in this bar about a hot question from a subject area that I am mostly active in, or say I can subscribe to hot questions from a particular tag of Stack Overflow, rather than from the whole bunch of tags available. Is that possible. May be we have have a fourth tab, that shows hot questions for the tags you have subscribed to.

Can that be done or **is there any other option where I can get notified about hot questions from a particular tag area.**

Comment: Answer can be found here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93150/to-get-the-notification-about-the-blackberry-questions-tagset